# how to reset the interactions window in dr java?

Tags: java, windows, reset

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to create a counter in a dr java program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1552166/how-to-create-a-counter-in-a-dr-java-program)

this is the code that I am working on...

I would like to know how to reset the interactions window after every question is asked so that the window is clear for the next question to be shown to the user but I do not want the Score to be reset either so that I can display the score at the end. I am looking for the correct syntax and code to do this.

```
//Neel Patel
//Friday October 9th, 2009
/*This is a quiz program that will ask the user 10 questions. the user will answer
 * these questions and will be scored out of 10.*/

class Quiz
{
  public static void main (String args[])
  {
    //Instructions
    System.out.println("instructions");
    System.out.println(" ");
    System.out.println("1. You wll be asked ten questions through out the quiz.");
    System.out.println("2. The first question will appear, you will have to answer that    question for the next question to appear.");
    System.out.println("3. When you answer the last question you will be told your score.");
    System.out.println(" ");

System.out.println("welcome to the basketball quiz.");
int Score=0;

  // question 1
  System.out.println(" ");
  System.out.println("Question 1. ");
  System.out.println("How tall is a basketball hoop? ");
  System.out.println("Type in Answer here:");
  String Question1= In.getString();
  if (Question1.equalsIgnoreCase("10 Feet"))
  {
    Score++;
    System.out.println("Correct!");

  }
  else
  {
    System.out.println("you got this questions wrong");
  }

   // question 2
  System.out.println(" ");
  System.out.println("Question 2. ");
  System.out.println("Who invented basketball? ");
  System.out.println("Type in Answer here:");
  String Question2= In.getString();
  if (Question2.equalsIgnoreCase("James Naismith"))
  {

    Score++;
    System.out.println("Correct!");

  }
  else
  {
    System.out.println("you got this questions wrong");
  }
  // question 3
  System.out.println(" ");
  System.out.println("Question 3. ");
  System.out.println("Who is the only person in the history of the NBA to average a triple double for an entier season?");
  System.out.println("Type in Answer here:");
  String Question3= In.getString();
  if (Question3.equalsIgnoreCase("Oscar Robertson"))
  {
    Score++;
    System.out.println("Correct!");

  }
  else
  {
    System.out.println("you got this questions wrong");
  }
   // question 4
  System.out.println(" ");
  System.out.println("Question 4. ");
  System.out.println("how many players was the first basketball game played with?");
  System.out.println("Type in Answer here:");
  String Question4= In.getString();
  if (Question4.equalsIgnoreCase("9 on 9||18"))
  {
    Score++;
    System.out.println("Correct!");

  }
  else
  {
    System.out.println("you got this questions wrong");
  }
  }
}
```

Comment: so all i have to do for it to reset is use Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cls"); 

i cannot use arrays because im in grade 11 and taking a computer science class.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a loop of some sort. So you can start by creating arrays to store the questions and answers like this:

```
String[] questions = {" \nQuestion 1. \nHow tall is a basketball hoop? \nType in Answer here:",
                  " \nQuestion 2. \nWho invented basketball? \nType in Answer here: "};
String[] answers = {"10 Feet", "James Naismith"};
int score = 0;
String ans = "";
```

Then you can write a loop like this:

```
for(int i = 0;i < questions.length; i++){
   System.out.println(questions[i]);
   ans= In.getString();
   if (ans.equalsIgnoreCase(answers[i]))
   {

    System.out.println("Correct!");
    score++;
    }
    else
    {
    System.out.println("you got this questions wrong");
    }
}
System.out.println(score);
```

And finally to clear the screen itself you cannot do that directly in Java but you may be able to run the cls command (assuming you run Windows) but that makes your code platform specific.

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cls");
```

Answer (score 0):

One brute-force (and, unlike `cls`, platform-independent) method for clearing the console  would be to print a whole bunch of newliness to the console.  This approach could have the added benefit of being seen as befitting an 11th grade CS project.